# Difference between the two sentences and why are they used in that particular way

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

I bought my friends some chocolates.

I bought some chocolates for my friends.

Comment: Only a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: If you were alone at the time, you would be more likely to use #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is shorter. Other than that, I would say that the meaning is exactly the same. The speaker purchased some chocolates to give to his/her friends.